# Archiving a huge SQL Server table with change data capture and foreign key constraints on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, foreign-key, change-data-capture, archive

We are trying to archive a huge table with ~170 million rows, which is partitioned, has change data capture (CDC) enabled and has ~5 foreign key constraints.

We decided on the archival since the daily full backup is taking a long time, and so we are planning to keep the archival table in different drive.

We tried the below ways, and all are taking really long:

- We can’t go for inserting latest data to another table and then rename the tables accordingly because of the foreign key constraints.
- SSIS package to insert to archive table old data is taking ~6 days in batch insert
- BCP is also taking ~7- days.

Please suggest any best idea/suggestions considering CDC and foreign keys.

Comment: If it's partitioned, why can't you switch out partitions you want to move?

Comment: Thank you Erik ! Even if we moved the partition to another drive, the daily full backup job will take the same long  time. We want to minimize this time

Comment: when you say ssis and bcp takes days - how much data you are inserting ?  Is this incremental load or full load everytime ?

Comment: I think the first question to ask is how old do records need to be before they are unable to be altered? You can only archive old data if it is going to be stable. If you are trying to archive data that is being altered, what is the point?

Comment: If you move it to a read only file group, you could skip it during backups.

Comment: Also it sounds, generally, like you've let this database grow beyond the capabilities of your infrastructure, and the procedure you propose won't really change that.